# Updateing SSBO Contents

Tags: opengl, glsl, shader, compute-shader

I am trying to do a simple calculation on a Compute Shader, where after doing one round of computation I give the result of that round back to the Shader as an Input for the second round.

My Compute shader looks like this:

```
#version 440 core

layout(std430, binding = 0) buffer Result{
  float out_picture[];
};
layout(std430, binding = 1) buffer In_p1{
  float in_p1[];
};
layout(local_size_x = 1000) in;

void main() {
  in_p1[gl_GlobalInvocationID.x] = 1.0f;
  out_picture[gl_GlobalInvocationID.x] = out_picture[gl_GlobalInvocationID.x] + in_p1[gl_GlobalInvocationID.x];

}
```

Her is my OpenGL code:

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {

    std::vector<float> result_container;
    std::vector<SSBO> ssbo_container;
    SSBO ssbo_result;

    ssbo_result.NUM_PIX = 1920*1080*4;
    ssbo_result.WORK_GROUP_SIZE = 1000;
    result_container.reserve(ssbo_result.NUM_PIX * sizeof(float));

    glGenBuffers(1, &ssbo_result.handle);
    glBindBufferBase(GL_SHADER_STORAGE_BUFFER, 0, ssbo_result.handle);
    glBufferData(GL_SHADER_STORAGE_BUFFER, ssbo_result.NUM_PIX * sizeof(float), NULL, GL_DYNAMIC_DRAW);

    for(unsigned int i = 1; i < 2; i++){
      SSBO ssbo;
      glGenBuffers(1, &ssbo.handle);
      glBindBufferBase(GL_SHADER_STORAGE_BUFFER, i, ssbo.handle);
      glBufferData(GL_SHADER_STORAGE_BUFFER, ssbo_result.NUM_PIX * sizeof(float), NULL, GL_DYNAMIC_DRAW);
      ssbo_container.push_back(ssbo);
    }

    while (!g_win.shouldClose()) {

      std::cout << "container:" << result_container[0] << std::endl;

      glUseProgram(g_avg_program);
      glDispatchCompute(ssbo_result.NUM_PIX / ssbo_result.WORK_GROUP_SIZE, 1, 1);
      glMemoryBarrier(GL_SHADER_STORAGE_BARRIER_BIT);
      glBindBufferBase(GL_SHADER_STORAGE_BUFFER, 0, 0);

      glBindBuffer(GL_SHADER_STORAGE_BUFFER, ssbo_result.handle);
      GLfloat *ptr = (GLfloat *) glMapBuffer(GL_SHADER_STORAGE_BUFFER, GL_READ_ONLY);
      memcpy(result_container.data(), ptr, ssbo_result.NUM_PIX * sizeof(float));
      glUnmapBuffer(GL_SHADER_STORAGE_BUFFER);

      glBindBuffer(GL_SHADER_STORAGE_BUFFER, ssbo_result.handle);
      ptr = (GLfloat *) glMapBuffer(GL_SHADER_STORAGE_BUFFER, GL_WRITE_ONLY);
      memcpy(ptr, result_container.data(), ssbo_result.NUM_PIX * sizeof(float));
      glUnmapBuffer(GL_SHADER_STORAGE_BUFFER);


      g_win.update();
      if (glfwGetKey(g_win.getGLFWwindow(), GLFW_KEY_ESCAPE) == GLFW_PRESS) {
        g_win.stop();
      }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

After initializing the ssbo's and calling `glDispatchCompute()` and `glMemoryBarrier(GL_SHADER_STORAGE_BARRIER_BIT)` I read out the result and saving it in `std::vector<float>result_container`. This fills the container with 1.0f as expected for the first run, `ssbo_result.handle` beeing my `out_picture` ssbo

I then try feeding the result back in as an input into `out_picture` the same way I read the data out of it by just flipping the memcpy dest and source, as I understand it that I now have my previous result in the `out_picture` GPU Memory

As you can see I am trying to add a value (here 1.0f) to the `out_picture` and feed it back as an input into `out_picture` for the next computation. The Idea is to just add the result as an input for the next run.
I tryed doing the same with `glCopyBufferSubData` with the same outcome. Only 1.0 as output everytime instead of a 1, 2, 3 ...

Comment: Why do you install the program in `read_Computation` and `update_StorageBuffer` - `glUseProgram(program)`? Where do you launch the computation - [`glDispatchCompute`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/glDispatchCompute.xhtml)? Do you use a memory barrier -  [`glMemoryBarrier(GL_BUFFER_UPDATE_BARRIER_BIT)`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/glMemoryBarrier.xhtml)?

Comment: @Rabbid76 I install the shader program because i have to use the ssbo assigned to it. I call the `glDispatchCompute()` and `glMemoryBarrier(GL_SHADER_STORAGE_BARRIER_BIT)` before my `read_compute()` and `update_StorageBuffer()`. I have wrote all the code in the main() so it should be complete

Comment: In the while loop *0* is bound to the binding point *0* (`glBindBufferBase(GL_SHADER_STORAGE_BUFFER, 0, 0)`), but this state is never changed again. The binding of `ssbo_result.handle` is lost after the first launch of the compute shader.

Comment: @Rabbid76 Thank's a bunch. Binding it again did the Trick!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the while loop *0* is bound to the binding point *0*, after the compute shader was launched:

```
while (!g_win.shouldClose()) {

    ....
    glDispatchCompute(ssbo_result.NUM_PIX / ssbo_result.WORK_GROUP_SIZE, 1, 1);
    glMemoryBarrier(GL_SHADER_STORAGE_BARRIER_BIT);
    glBindBufferBase(GL_SHADER_STORAGE_BUFFER, 0, 0);
    ....
}
```

but `ssbo_result.handle` is never bound to the binding point *0* again. This causes that the computation operates only in the first cycle of the loop, because the binding to the shader storage buffer is broken in the further cycles of the loop.

It is completely superfluous to break the binding of the buffer, since the binding point is not used for anything else.

Delete the line `glBindBufferBase(GL_SHADER_STORAGE_BUFFER, 0, 0);` in the loop, to solve the issue. (Of course binding the buffer continuously at the begin of the `while` loop, would do the job, too - add `glBindBufferBase(GL_SHADER_STORAGE_BUFFER, 0, ssbo_result.handle);` before `glDispatchCompute`)